# AJAX post doesn't send parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I can't figure out why AJAX doesn't send any parameters in POST. It returned a 403 error, probably because of CSRFTOKEN so I've decorated the `view` using `@csrfexempt` but now it doesn't send any parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cancel_reservation = $('.cancel-reservation');
    var confirm_reservation = $('.confirm-reservation');
    var reservation_id = $(this).data('reservation_id');

    cancel_reservation.on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/ajax/reservation/cancel/',
            data:{reservation_id:reservation_id},
            success:function(){
                alert('canceled');
            }
        });

    })
});
```

**VIEW**

```
@csrf_exempt
def reservation_cancel(request):
    print request.POST
    id = request.POST['reservation_id']
    va_models.Reservation.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    return JsonResponse({'status_code': 'success'})
```

The `print request.POST` prints `<QueryDict: {}>` and

```
request.POST['reservation_id']
```

raises:

```
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key)) MultiValueDictKeyError: "'reservation_id'"
```

Do you know where could be the problem?

Comment: do you get id when you `console.log(reservation_id);` on click?

Comment: From where you are getting the value for $(this).data('reservation_id');

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data:{'reservation_id':reservation_id},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json",` to your ajax header